# finding intermediate fields of field extensions: simple method vs. Galois theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am looking for a straightforward way to find all intermediate fields of a field extension. Let's take the splitting field of $X^3-2$ over $\Bbb Q$ as an example.

If we adjoin the roots of $X^3-2$ to $\Bbb Q$ we get $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta_3)$ with $\zeta_3$ a primitive root of unity different from $1$. My idea for finding the intermediate fields would be to look at the $\Bbb Q$-basis derived from the minimal polynomials of the successive extensions $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta_3)/\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})/\Bbb Q$.

This basis would be $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2}, (\sqrt[3]{2})^2, \zeta_3, \zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta_3 (\sqrt[3]{2})^2\}$. Now I look for basis elements which can be turned into other basis elements by field operations like squaring, adding, etc. This is obviously the case for $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ but also $(\zeta_3 (\sqrt[3]{2})^2)^2 = -2\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2}$. So I get the following intermediate fields: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3)$, $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{2})$.

Does this method give me all intermediate fields? If yes, what's the advantage of an analysis using Galois theory? If no, what am I missing?

Comment: Interesting "challenge" to Galois theory! But/and, the fatal issue is that intermediate fields could conceivably (in general, if not necessarily in your example) be generated by _linear_ _combinations_ of whatever basis elements one chooses. Maybe not, in some examples, as in your "simple method", but that needs proof... which is "field theory" and "Galois theory".

Comment: @Marc Btw, you missed one intermediate field extension.

Comment: @paul: can you please give an example where this occurs?

Comment: @user26857: can you please tell me which one, so I can see where the method goes wrong?

Comment: @Marc $\Bbb Q(\zeta_3^2 \sqrt[3]{2})$

Comment: Ah, ok, yes I forgot this one. This is also generated by the basis element $\zeta_3 (\sqrt[3]{2})^2$, so it hasn't much to do with the method.

Comment: Depending on what you mean about "turned into basis elements by field operations", inside $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)$ (fifth root of unity) there is a unique subfield $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})$. Is this addressing your question?

Comment: Thanks, I need to think about this

Answer (score 1):

How do you **prove** you've found all possible relations between basis elements? This is especially difficult if you're unlucky in your choice of basis, or in how the field is given. For example, the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ can just as validly be presented as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4}-5\sqrt[3]{2} + \zeta_3)$. What do you do now?

More importantly, how do you know you've captured all intermediate fields $\mathbb{Q}\subset K\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ that are of the form $K=\mathbb{Q}(a)$ for some $a$ that's not a basis element?

Comment: I don't know how to prove what you ask for. But if the field extension is given the way you write it, I can still try to successively add the elements and analyze the minimal polynomials which leads me to $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta_3)$.

Comment: Your second objection seems fatal because it implies that the method wouldn't work even if one could prove what you asked me to. Can you please give an example of such a situation? I think I haven't seen this yet.