# How to describe lattice of subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})$

Tags: extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

I have to describe lattice of subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})$.
     I know that :
         $$[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13}):\mathbb{Q}]=\phi(13)=12$$

And   $$\zeta_{13}=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{13}} $$   with    $k=0 ,...,12$
       I think that  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt13)$ of degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$, it is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})$ but I don't know how to go on...

Comment: We know that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}.$ Did you have a look at similar questions here at MSE? Just follow [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463968/finding-the-intermediate-fields-of-bbbq-zeta-7) with $13$ instead of $7$.

Comment: I still haven't done galois group in my course. So I have to use other arguments

Comment: Have a look at the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320494/finding-intermediate-fields-of-field-extensions-simple-method-vs-galois-theory); they also apply here.